# The use of data attribute for style information vs multiple classes

Tags: css, html, svg

I have been creating an interactive webpage. The main part is a SVG map. This map has ~600 text labels and these text labels currently have several classes. A current example is below

```
<text class="UCWF left base" x="1513.8158" y="733.91864"><tspan x="1513.8158" y="733.91864">Canary Wharf</tspan></text>
```

In the class attribute "UCWF" is a unique station code. (unique to the station but there is also a rectangle representing the station itself so I cannot move this information to an id tag.) The second entry sets the stying for the station being to the left of the text. The final part says wether it is the upper or lower part of the station name. (Some have two so that they appear over the background)
This already seams like a cumbersome solution and it is about to get worse. To each station I want to add information telling if the station has level access for wheelchairs and if you can take bicycles there. To me the obvious solution would be to add this as data attributes

> data-cycle="true" data-wheelchair="false"

However I am only going to use this information to affect the text styling. Selecting a button marked wheelchair will set all stations with no wheelchair access to grey and others black so this naturally seams to belong as a class and styling issue.
So the Key Question is does this functionality belong in styling or data? Are there possible limitations in the future from the choice.
I believe both would work. As background I am new to web coding but am interested in following best practise where possible

Comment: The SVG is within an html webpage. I can post a link to the existing version but was unsure if this was promoting or in someother way frowned upon

Comment: It's not the "promoting" that's the problem, but the fact that external sites are prone to changing or disappearing.

Comment: data attributes are not supported by SVG. If you had standalone SVG files served as XML then you could put your data in a namespace. You can still use data attributes but you'd have to access them using getAttribute and not the HTML data attribute access API.

Answer (score 0):

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes)

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

So, if your're using that information only for styling purposes, is better use the `class` attribute (or `style` if you don't want to use separate CSS).

The only possible limitation that comes to my mind is that seeing that piece of code in the future you might think that `data-*` attributes has some kind of special features not related to style.